# Making Two Views have The Same Center Height iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

So my problem is, I have two views and I want their y coordinate's center to be the same. I want the views to be perfectly aligned so their center y coordinate is the same. I need the view to feel like they are around the same height. Let me provide an image to help explain what I am talking about: [image]

In the picture it shows that the cart's center y coordinate isn't aligned with the Leaderboard Button's center. How do I make the center of the cart aligned with the leaderboard button's center to give it a better look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Auto Layout (in storyboards or code)

or...

```
leftView.center.y = rightView.center.y
```

Comment: I am using auto layout, but is there a specific constraint to make their centers be aligned that I can add?

Comment: Ctrl+drag from one view to another, then choose 'Center Vertically'

Comment: Ok, I did that and it worked so I will accept your answer but it is making me wait seven minutes...

Answer (score 1):

There is a Center Y attribute in auto layout. Set one Center Y equivalent to the other Center Y.

If you are using code, this is how you do it:

```
let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cartImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: leaderboardsButton, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
centerY.active = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, both answers worked so I up voted :).